# Avocado leaf veins problem

Tags: trees, diagnosis, pruning, avocado

I have 1-year old indoor avocado tree. Recetly, I noticed gray / brown spots around its veins. What is the problem and how to fix it?
[image: Avocado leaf veins problem]

Avocado was firstly pruned 4 days ago. I am not sure if the problem was there before or not.

Comment: Did you add anything to the soil?

Comment: Only water, no fertilizer.

Comment: Its hard to be sure because of the lack of 3d.  Are the spots raised ?  They look like eggs or bugs to me.